# Filling a WinRT control with repeated texture

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there any native WinRT tool for filling control with repeated image. I don't want to have it scaled to the parents width, just repeated as much times as it fits through X direction. I've read that it seems to be a missing part of WinRT `ImageBrush` class. Was WPF `TileMode` properity replaced by some other tool?

[Here](http://www.robfe.com/tag/winrt/) I've found an external solution. Besides I've seen that it can be handled by cooperating with CSS.

Comment: WPF and WinRT/XAML are different technologies. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used an approach similar to the one you linked (putting multiple Image controls tiled in a panel) and it is probably the best you can do for now. There is nothing built-in other than manually blitting the tiled image into a WriteableBitmap or using DirectX interop to render the tiled image.

Another option is to simply save the tiled image using some image editing application and simply scale it (e.g. with Stretch="UniformToFill") to the screen size. If you simply tile it at the native screen resolution - the pixels will remain sharp, but at higher resolution screens you might start noticing the pattern, which might spoil the effect.